# NUnit Raise event on abstract class attempt fails

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

Why does this NUnit test below fail? Or why is the event is never triggered?

```
public interface IGo
{
    event Action<bool> GoNow;
}

public abstract class Goer : IGo
{
    public virtual event Action<bool> GoNow = delegate {};
}

[Test]
public void VerifyNUnitRaise()
{
    var mock = new Mock<Goer> {CallBase = true};
    var hit = false;
    mock.Object.GoNow += b => hit = b;
    mock.Raise(g => g.GoNow += null, true);

    Assert.IsTrue(hit);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Moq 4.1.1311.

Comment: I can use `var imock = mock.As<IGo>();` and then raise the event on the `imock`. That seems unnecessary, though, and much more difficult to implement in my real-world scenario.

Comment: This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=335. You need to set `CallBase = false` or use the `IGo` interface instead of the `Goer` class.